# Bootstrap 4 Dynamic Carousel using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to add images dynamically to a Bootstrap Carousel but it just shows them in a list (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOCBe.jpg).

The images are National Parks Service API urls (https://www.nps.gov/common/uploads/structured_data/3C86AAE7-1DD8-B71B-0BA8BC5E5E895E98.jpg).

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
    <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for(let j = 0; j < parkInfo.data[i].images.length; j++) {
  $('<div class="item"><img src="'+parkInfo.data[i].images[j].url+'" width="50%">   </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
  $('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'+j+'"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')

}
  $('.item').first().addClass('active');
  $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
  $('#carousel').carousel();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to have a class on the item 'carousel-item' not 'item'.

https://jsfiddle.net/orb9945u/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        $('<div class="carousel-item"><img 
          src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" width="50%">   
          </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        $('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'+j+'"> 
          </li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')

    }

    $('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
    $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
    $('#carousel').carousel();
});
```

Comment: This works but now when I click on the arrows the image doesn't change.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? It works there. What you need to do is change the class from 'item' to 'carousel-item' in the jQuery code.

Comment: I had to add click events for the arrows to work but thank you for getting the carousel to work!

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

```js
for(let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                   $('<div class="item"><img src="'+data[j].imageName+'"></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
                   $('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'+j+'"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators');
              }
              $('.item').first().addClass('active');
              $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
              $('#carousel').carousel();
```