# Trying to add images to carousel dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am using jquery, bootstrap and try to create a carousel.

The carousel is working if I give carousel items statically but if I try to add images to carousel dynamically it failing.

```
jQuery script:

function loadPartners(section) {
       var partners = section.partners;
        // partners contain list of URL where the images are located.
        $.each(partners, function( i, val ) {           
            console.log("success partners val: " + val.url);
            var markup = "<div class=carousel-item> <div class=\"listing-item compact\" ><a  class=listing-img-container><div class=listing-img-content><span class=listing-compact-title> Day-View </span></div><img src=" + val.url+ "></a></div></div>";

            // Adding carousel item to  carousel
            $('#partners #partners1 #partners2 #partners3').append(markup);                     
        });
 }


HMTL code.

<div id = "partners" class="container" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div id = "partners1" class="row" style="opacity: 1;">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4 class="headline margin-top-70 margin-bottom-30">Partners</h4>

        </div>

        <!-- Carousel -->
        <div id = "partners2" class="col-md-8">
            <div id = "partners3" class="carousel">
            <!--  items will be added here    -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel / End -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Observations:

1. Opacity of  is getting set to zero automatically.
2. If the opacity is made 1 in the browser inspect element, I see partner images visible but its paginated instead of appearing with in Carousel.

3.If I set the carousel item statically everything works fine.

Comment: Have found a similar thread, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343760/bootstrap-4-dynamic-carousel-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Please try to initialize carousel manually after you will add all needed items:

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

It can be found in bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

via javascript section.

Also to make sure your carousel will not be initialized earlier replace carousel class with something different like: 'carousel-custom'. With that bootstrap will not initialize it automatically using your html markup.